# Include a javascript library for calculation

Tags: include, dependencies, javascript

I want to do something very simple in javascript. I have a main.js file which needs to call a calculation method in math.js.

If I include in index.html these two files with script tag, first math.js and then main.js, am I garanteed that math.js will have finished loaded before I can use it in main.js ?

If not, would I need to do some overkilled hack like I read here [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) or even worse because I can't even see in that link how dependency is actually taken into account.

Update: Why can't I do like what Dashcode seems to do [How can I add my library to be loaded Dashcode parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749767/how-can-i-add-my-library-to-be-loaded-dashcode-parts) ie just use document.write('...')? Is in fact document.write robust enough on a very slow connection if the library was bigger than main.js ?

Comment: You are not guranteed that the files will finish loading before loading the next script file. I just found this, but it MAY be what you are looking for: http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a variable in math.js and proove in main.js if this variable exist.

```
var mathLoaded = true;
```

in main.js:

```
function loaded() {
    return ((typeof mathLoaded) !== 'undefined');
}
```

Edit:

Now you can start an wait function, until it is loaded:

```
function wait() {
    if(loaded()) {
        //doSomething();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function() { wait(); }, 0);
    }
}

window.setTimeout(function() { wait(); }, 0);
```

Comment: And what should I do if it isn't loaded yet :)

Comment: Great will try it :) Could this solution also work see my post update

Comment: Note that you might rather do `setTimeout(wait, 4)` since the minimum delay is 4.

Comment: The 4 doesn't matter since it will be slower than 0 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to make sure dependencies get loaded

also, JS gets loaded and parsed top-bottom. whichever comes first in the source gets fetched first and parsed first (but it doesn't guarantee order as servers for some files may be slow). that's why it's recommended that if you use libraries and toolkits (like jQuery and others), they should be loaded before anything else.

Comment: RequireJS seems a good solution. If there is no other solution that is lighter I think I'll have no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

No you are not. The files can be loaded in any order. You typically want to call your initial code from the documents `load` event. That even it triggered once all the files needed for the page are loaded.

Comment: Really? I wonder how jQuery plugins can be loaded correctly in that case; as it's required to load them after the jQuery core.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `window.onload`?

```
window.onload = function () {
    //your code here.
}
```

or get really fancy with a cross-browser `addEvent` function?

```
var libJS = {
    addEvent: function (obj, type, fn) {
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
            return true;
        } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj['e' + type + fn] = fn;
            obj[type + fn] = function () {
                obj['e' + type + fn](window.event);
            }
            var r = obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fn]);
            return r;
        } else {
            obj['on' + type] = fn;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

which attaches functions to events properly...

```
libJS.addEvent(window, 'load', someMainJsFunction); //add to window.onload
```